# Count the number of times multiple substrings appear in dataframe column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a list of sentences in one column and am trying to create a new column equal to the number of times a list of strings show up.

For example, the relevant dataframe looks like

```
book['sentences']
0 The brown dog jumped over the big moon
1 The brown fox slid under the brown log
```

I'm trying to count the number of times "brown", "over", and "log" show up in each sentences (i.e. the new column would be equal to 2 and 3).

I know I can do this with str.count, but only for one string at a time and then I would have to add them up

```
book['count_brown'] = book['sentences'].str.count('brown')
book['count_over'] = book['sentences'].str.count('over')
book['count_log'] = book['sentences'].str.count('log')
book['count'] = book['count_brown']+book['count_over']+book['count_log']
```

My list of strings I am searching for is over 300 words long so even with a loop it doesn't seem optimal. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to piRSquared's solution, but uses `get_dummies` and `sum` for the counts.

```
df
                                sentences
0  The brown dog jumped over the big moon
1  The brown fox slid under the brown log

words = ['brown', 'over', 'log']
df = df.sentences.str.extractall('({})'.format('|'.join(words)))\
                           .iloc[:, 0].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
df
   brown  log  over
0      1    0     1
1      2    1     0
```

---

If you want row-wise counts of *all* words in a single column, just sum along the first axis.

```
df.sum(1)
0    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Ganky!

```
lst = ['brown', 'over', 'log']

book['sentences'].str.extractall(
    '({})'.format('|'.join(lst))
).groupby(level=0)[0].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

0  brown  log  over
0      1    0     1
1      2    1     0
```

Comment: What does Ganky mean?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nasty gross terrible

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `nltk` Frequency distribution you can do that very easily i.e

```
import nltk 
lst = ['brown', 'over', 'log']
ndf = df['sentences'].apply(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize).apply(nltk.FreqDist).apply(pd.Series)[lst].fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
   brown  over  log
0    1.0   1.0  0.0
1    2.0   0.0  1.0
```

For sum

```
ndf['count'] = ndf.sum(1)
```

```
   brown  over  log  count
0    1.0   1.0  0.0    2.0
1    2.0   0.0  1.0    3.0
```